# oracle query is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables named LOGIN and LOGIN_LOG. In LOGIN_LOG table, datetime of every login of every user is saved. in both tables EMP_CODE is common column. I have to pick All usernames, locations from login table and their "last login time" from LOGIN_LOG table. I have tried something like this but not working. please help.

```
SELECT 
LOGIN."NAME",
LOGIN.LOCATION,
LOGIN.WORKING_STATUS,
LV.LOGINDATETIME
FROM 
LOGIN 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT 
 LOGIN_LOG.EMP_CODE, 
 LOGIN_LOG.LOGINDATETIME 
 FROM LOGIN_LOG 
 ORDER BY LOGIN_LOG.LOGINDATETIME DESC
) AS LV
ON LOGIN.EMP_CODE=LV.EMP_CODE 
WHERE LOGIN.USER_TYPE='NSA';
```

Comment: it gives error- ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: @mareckmareck: absolutely not. Columns (identifiers) are quoted using double quotes. Single quotes are for character literals.

Comment: It's not single quoute, it's a back qoute. But actualy you are right, in Oracle you use double quoutes.

Comment: @mareckmareck: a backtick is just as wrong as a single quote. Standard SQL (and Oracle) uses double quotes for identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support using `AS` for a table alias.

Plus, you query doesn't make sense. There is no need for the derived table for the outer and an `order by` in a derived table or sub-query does not make any sense at all.

So it should be something like this:

```
SELECT login.name,
       login.location,
       login.working_status,
       lv.logindatetime
FROM login
  LEFT OUTER JOIN login_log lv ON login.emp_code = lv.emp_code
WHERE login.user_type = 'NSA'
```

**Edit**: I overlooked your requirement to get the last login:

```
SELECT login.name,
       login.location,
       login.working_status,
       lv.logindatetime
FROM login
  LEFT JOIN (
     select emp_code, max(logindatetime) as logindatetime
     from login_log
     group by emp_code
 )  lv ON login.emp_code = lv.emp_code
WHERE login.user_type = 'NSA'
```

Comment: not working. if login_log.logindatetime is lv then how this column is possible lv.emp_code. the error is ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @user3807573: Sorry I just copied your code. Overlooked the error you made. Corrected now

Comment: i already did it but it is giving all logindateTime but i have to choose only last login date time of every user as described in my question.

Comment: @user3807573: see my edit. I overlooked your requirement to get the latest login

Answer (score 0):

The query above is a bit confusing. In my opinion, the subquery is wrong. You cannot rely on any ordering of the results after a join. In other words, if u have a table A and a table B, both sorted and you make a join, you cannot be sure that the joined result is sorted as well.

I would suggest (without knowing what "does not work" means in your case):

```
SELECT L."NAME", L.LOCATION, L. WORKING_STATUS, LG.LOGINDATETIME
FROM LOGIN L
JOIN LOGIN_LOG LG on L.EMP_CODE=LG.EMP_CODE
WHERE L.USER_TYPE='NSA'
ORDER BY LG.LOGINDATETIME DESC
```

Always prefer joins over subqueries if possible, since the dbms can handle them better (with optimization, index, etc.)

**EDIT:**

of course, the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is not needed here and could produce an overhead at the query executor so better use `JOIN` instead.

**EDIT2:**

I think now I got the problem. You need to use a `GROUP BY` instead of a `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT L."NAME", L.LOCATION, L. WORKING_STATUS, MAX(LG.LOGINDATETIME) AS LOGINDATETIME
FROM LOGIN L
JOIN LOGIN_LOG LG on L.EMP_CODE=LG.EMP_CODE
WHERE L.USER_TYPE='NSA'
GROUP BY L."NAME", L.LOCATION, L.WORKING_STATUS
```

Comment: i already did it but it is giving all logindateTime but i have to choose only last login date time of every user as described in my question

Comment: so you need for each user the datetime of last login?

Comment: yes. actually in LOGIN_LOG table there is a record for the date time of each login of every user. I have to choose the last one.